# How to check the nth call args in Jamine

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

In `jest` there is a method called `.toHaveBeenNthCalledWith` which you can pass the `nth` call and check if that call was with specific params.

Now I want to check the same in `jasmine` (in angular unit tests), what is the the way in jasmine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Spy#calls argsFor(index)](https://jasmine.github.io/api/3.5/Spy_calls.html).

```
const mySpy = spyOn(myObject, 'methodName');

// do some stuff

expect(myObject.methodName).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expectedNumberOfInvocations);
const arguments = mySpy.calls.argsFor(nthInvocation);

// check arguments
```